# How to pivot on multiple fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+
| ID |  Item  |    Date    | Category |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
|  1 | xyz    | 3/12/2013  | A        |
|  2 | xyz    | 3/23/2013  | A        |
|  3 | j423   | 4/19/2013  | C        |
|  4 | 9d98df | 4/16/2013  | B        |
|  5 | j423   | 5/13/2013  | C        |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
```

I want to group the data in columns both by `Date` (by month) and by `Category`, like so:

```
       3/2013    | 4/2013
Item   A | B | C | A | B | C
xyz      |   |   |   |   |    
j423     |   |   |   |   |
9d98df   |   |   |   |   |
```

I know that I can group the data by having a function that returns the date as month/year and then pivot on the month field, and I can create a composite-key field with, e.g.

```
select item, getMonth(date) & category as month_category from myTable
```

and then pivot on `month_category` to give me:

```
Item   A_3/2013 | B_3/2013 | C_3/2013 | A_4/2013 | B_4/2013 | C_4/2013
xyz             |          |          |          |          |    
j423            |          |          |          |          |    
9d98df          |          |          |          |          |
```

But this won't give me a report where I have the two layers of columns shown above.  Is there a way to do this in Access?  Or am I stuck with the composite column names?

Comment: Is this a query? Or a report?

Comment: @Lisa: I'll take whatever approach will allow me to present the data in the two-layered column format.  With a query I can only have one row of column headers, so it would have to be a report, right?

Comment: Yes, it would have to be a report. MS Access does have a report wizard to walk you through the process, though.

Comment: What values are you looking to get out of said Pivot?  A simple count of Items sold by Category and month?

Comment: Which field would you like to aggregate? I haven;t seen it ;(

Answer (score 1):

> am I stuck with the composite column names

You are "stuck" with the composite column names in the crosstab query, but you can format the report using a group header with multiple stacked labels if you feel so inclined. Don't confuse the ***data*** (the results returned by the query) with the ***presentation of the data*** (the report layout).

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to get pivot query with two-line headers. To display data, use MS Access report. I would suggest to create pivot query data in that way:

```
Item  | Month  |A | B | C |
xyz   | 3/2013 |  |   |   |
xyz   | 4/2013 |  |   |   |
```

Then you'll be able to group or summarize data on month/item.

For further information, please see:
[Create a grouped or summary report](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-HA010006894.aspx)
[Grouping records on date/time values in an Access report](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/grouping-records-on-date-time-values-in-an-access-report-HA001034582.aspx)